# How to use MIME and CID to embed an email signature written in HTML and inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, email, mime, signature

I have been having lots of problems getting a clients email signature to work.

It was all working fine until I tried to get it to display on an iPhone. I started looking in to all sorts of different options and came across using Base64 encoding. However, looking in to using this alone it seems that it is not supported in many email clients.

I have now come across using CID and MIME but cannot find any reference for how to use these ideas in relation to an HTML coded signature. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Will I be able to successfully use MIME and CID to be able to create individual signatures for the four different employees who work at the company?

Comment: Hi Dave, I run into same problem. Have you got any solution for it?

Comment: I'm afraid not @FaisalAshfaq i just ended up aborting mission and vowing never to make another email signature with images!

Comment: That is what I am thinking now. Can you give a look at my question anyway? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412914/using-eml-for-html-mail-signature/25413176#25413176

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this for css and I'm not much of a web-technology guy, so I don't know how to reference external css files in HTML, so this may or may not work, but this is how you'd do it for images so it *should* work for css.

What you need to do is construct a multipart/related MIME part that contains the text/html MIME part as the first child. The "attachments" that are referenced via a CID URI should be added after the text/html part and have a Content-Location header with the CID URI as the value.

so... something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; boundary="aboundarystring"

--aboundarystring
Content-Type: text/html

... some HTML that references the following parts via a cid: URI ...
--aboundarystring
Content-Type: text/css; name="my.css"
Content-Location: cid:my.css

... css goes here ...
--aboundarystring--
```

Hope that helps.